# Getting aggregate data from table

Tags: spring, spring-data

I want to get aggregate data from a table using spring data.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_1, MAX(FIELD_1) AS MAX_1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE GROUP_ID = :groupId")
Mono<SummaryEntity> getSummary(@Param("groupId" Long groupId));
```

```
package com.refinitiv.eit.kv.label.enity.response;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SummaryResponse {
    @Column("TOTAL_1")
    private Double total_1;
    @Column("MAX_1")
    private Double max_1;
}
```

However I get this error : "Could not read property @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id() " ...

There should be no ID, only a single row with the summary data.

Any ideas on getting the summary data?

(the code is more complex but cleared up for this)

Comment: When asking about an error relative to some code, post the code, and post the exact and complete error. Is this supposed to be spring-data-jpa? Something else? What?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need your entity SummaryResponse to be managed by JPA and eventually persist it, you need to annotate it as @Entity and assign it either id or composite id (annotated with @Id).

If you just want to use that DTO for fetching the data, you can use a Spring's interface based projection for that:

```
public interface SummaryResponseProjection{
   getTotal1();
   getMax1();
}
```

and then use it for mapping the results of the query:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_1, MAX(FIELD_1) AS MAX_1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE GROUP_ID = :groupId")
Mono<SummaryResponseProjection> getSummary(@Param("groupId" Long groupId));
```

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting the same error...

`Could not read property @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id() @org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column(keyColumn=, value=LABEL_ID)private java.lang.Long package.db.LabelEntity.id from result set!`

(`LABEL_ID` is the primary key ID of the actual underlying table)

Comment: Do you have your id variable annotated as @Id? If so, check that the Id annotation is imported as javax.persistence.Id

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason:

This method was part of a repository defined as `ReactiveCrudRepository<RawEntity, Long>`, with `RawEntity` having the id defined.

Moving the method into a new repo defined as `ReactiveCrudRepository<SummaryEntity, Void>` solves the issue.

Thanks all!